# Undefined Variable, Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've got a quick question. Haskell is throwing the `57 - Undefined variable "f" error` at me and I've no idea why. I'd appreciate it if you could have a look at this.

Code:

```
eval :: Expr -> Environment -> Float
eval expr env = eval' expr
    where
    eval' :: Expr-> Float
    eval' (Num num) = num
    eval' (App app exprs) = foldl1 (f) (map eval' exprs) -- **Line 57**
    eval' (Id id) = 5
        where
        f = getFunctionForApp app                    -- **f is here** 
        getFunctionForApp :: String -> (Float->Float->Float)
        getFunctionForApp "+" = (+)
        getFunctionForApp "-" = (-)
        getFunctionForApp "*" = (*)
        getFunctionForApp "/" = (/)
        getIdVal :: String -> Environment -> Float
        getIdVal id ((curId, val):envrs) 
            |curId == id = val
            | otherwise = getIdVal id envrs
```

Type definition:

```
data Expr = Num Float | Id String | App String [ Expr ]
           deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
type Environment = [ ( String, Float ) ]
```

Comment: i honestly don't know the answer but I thought that the where block had to come after the statment. In other words, have you tried moving the whole where block up one line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The where block applies only to the case directly before it, not to all cases of the `eval'` function. So `f` is defined (but not used) in `eval' (Id id) = 5`, but it's not in scope in line 57. To fix this you need to move the where block directly after line 57.

Comment: Or just put "f = ..." right after the last "eval'" line -- having a where block nested inside another where block seems strange to me, though perhaps there are good reasons for it in some cases.

Comment: @MatrixFrog: Yes, there are sometimes very good reasons to nest `where`s; if you manually apply a 'static argument transformation', for example. Here, the nested `where` is used to create a short name for something using a value bound in the pattern, which is also a common use.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly what sepp2k said. In this case, though, I'd prefer simply swapping lines 57 and 58, so the `where` is attached to the right equation without splitting the equations for `eval'`, that's more readable.

Or don't use `f` at all, make it

```
eval' (App app exprs) = foldl1 (getFunctionOrApp app) (map eval' exprs)
eval' (Id id) = 5

getFunctionOrApp :: String -> (Float -> Float -> Float)
getFunctionOrApp "+" = ...
```

Moving `getFunctionOrApp` (and `getIdVal`) to the same-level `where` as `eval'`, it may even be reasonable to define them at the top level.